# python returns array[value] and need value only

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
###
while i<81 :
  j=0
  for value, j,k in dict.values():
    if temp[i] == value:
        break
  tup=(ages_train[i],net_worths_train[i],value)
  cleaned_data.append(tup)
  i=i+1
i=0
while i<81:
  print cleaned_data[i]
  i=i+1

print len(cleaned_data)
```

output these

```
(array([57]), array([ 338.08951849]), array([ 0.08308344]))

(array([57]), array([ 344.21586776]), array([ 0.60619895]))

(array([34]), array([ 243.79287312]), array([ 1.07834246]))
```

needed

```
(57,338.08951849,0.08308344)
```

Comment: You are going to need to tidy up your indentation before people can try to understand your question

Comment: i am new to this website, you can tell me what you didn't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

```
  tup=(ages_train[i],net_worths_train[i],value)
```

is returning a tuple of three arrays of size 1, why not just index into the arrays further when you construct the tuple?

```
  tup=(ages_train[i][0],net_worths_train[i][0],value[0])
```

If that doesn't work (and I do not know if it will because I have no idea the structure of your containers), then you ought to consider posting more code for context.